# CSS Grid Collapsible Row

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to draw a css grid where the first row has the following behavior:

1. when the row is visible, it should take a defined height, like 33% of the grid, **even if there's no content inside the row**
2. when the row is hidden (e.g display: none), it should take no space, and the second row should expand its content

I've done something similar [here](https://codepen.io/manudones/pen/JjopXZy)

```js
function toggle(index) {
  var collapse = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse')[index];
  collapse.classList.toggle("hide")
}
```

```css
.collapse {
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: collapse;
}
.right {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: right;
}
.left {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: left;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(100px) 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "left collapse" "left right";
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="toggle(0)">toggle collapse</button>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="collapse"><br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/> <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/> <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/> <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/> <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/>c <br/> c<br/> c<br/></div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>

<br/>

<button onClick="toggle(1)">toggle collapse</button>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="collapse"></div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

The first example works as expceted, the problem is that if there's no content inside the 'collapse' div, the height is not set (second example)

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(100px) 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "left collapse" "left right";
}
```

I'd like if that could be done only with css-grid properties.

Thanks!

Comment: Set the height before you perform the action with javascript. Take it's current height, apply it, and then change it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the purpose but,
What about giving .collapse a fix height ? Like :

```
.collapse {
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: collapse;
  height: 80px;
}
```

Or a min-height ?

Hope this could help.

Comment: yes that's the idea, I was hoping to find a css grid property to do that.

The purpose is to have a grid with the height of the first row like 33% (even when the row doesn't have any content inside), but when the row is hidden (e.g clicking a button), the row doesn't take any space, and the second row take also the space of the first one...